# How does one extend magento. Not build an extesion, but acutally fix magento

Tags: api

I've found a smidge of a hole in some of the core magento api. There doesn't seem to be a way to create configurable products.

Now I know there's a way to extend magento on my system, or install any number of plug-ins.  I however am a simple man, and I rather love the DRY principle.  I figure if there are 1000 people out there kludging something, then someone should actually fix it so they don't have to anymore.

I'd like to offer up a plug-in as a new core api.  I'm wondering how one would do this.

Answer (score 4):

No matter how awesome your plug-in may be, I don't think you're going to find the core team very receptive to adding what is essentially a third-party addition to the core.

I think your best bet would be to set something up on GitHub and begin promoting your extension. With time, you may draw enough attention that the core team notices and may consider beginning the process of adding something to the core.

That said, I can't imagine the core team is focused on adding new core features to the 1.x series with 2.x in the pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

You get a job, (or curry favor), with the people who work in eBay's Magento division.  In other words, you probably don't fix the core issue as a project outsider.

Magento has always favored a centralized, close-door approach to development.  They make something, release it under [an open source license](http://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0), listen to what people say about it, and then release something else.

There have been times during Magento's life where, if you [signed a contributors agreement](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/MCA-Magento-Contributor-Agreement-230909.pdf) with Varien Inc. or Magento Inc. (the two corporate entities that were "The Magento Startup" pre-acquisition with eBay), you could submit patches for bugs and/or new features.  However, that petered out (post acquisition?), and contributors were blocked from Magento's internal Bug tracker where information was spread and patches submitted.

Right now Magento's in a weird limbo state.  Internally, their development team is working on Magento 2, [and dropping code every so often into GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2).  They accept bugs and consider pull requests/patches there.  However, the original [Magento 1 CE bug tracker](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/report/) is off line right now.  The last time Magento [spoke semi-publicly](https://www.meanbee.com/news/magento-community-update.html) about this it sounded like 1.8 would be the final Magento CE release, and new efforts would focus on Magento 2.

Comment: it'd be nice if they opened back up a little. The community has a lot of mature features to offer these days. by mprototype